# CSS Nav Positioning Problem | HTML Burger Menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Hello!** Recently i've been building a website portfolio and have made a burger menu!

In the time so building the burger menu i've had troubles with positioning the *logo* and the *social icons*, **above and below** the href links.

Here is some images to understand what it looks like -

***NavBar (full) :***
[image]

***NavBar (burger before) :***
[image]
***NavBar (burger after) :***
[image]
***NavBar (burger after EXAMPLE) :***
[image]

I understand that this is happening because they are all located *inside* nav.

How can I modify it to have the *logo* **above** the text, and the *icons* **below** the text. I tried going around trying JS to add style to logo and icons but it seems to not work. Also changing the css in the media query (to when the burger pops up) can mess up the look "before" the burger is pressed.

html code -

```html
<div class="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="src/assets/TWINLOGO.png" style="width: 100px;height: 100px;"></a></div>
            <div class="openMenu"><i class="fa fa-bars" style="color:black;"></i></div>
            <ul class="mainMenu">
                <!-- Center-aligned links -->
                <div class="nav-center">
                    <div class="navLogo"><a href="index.html"><img src="src/assets/TWINLOGO.png" style="width: 100px;height: 100px;"></a></div>
                </div>
                <!-- Left-aligned links -->
                <li><a href="contact.html" class="leftLinks">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html" class="leftLinks">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://twins-merch-5.creator-spring.com/" target="_blank" class="leftLinks">Store</a></li>
                <div class="closeMenu"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div>
                <!-- Right-aligned links -->
                <div class="nav-right">
                    <span class="icons">
                        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/c/TwinPlayz_YT/?sub_confirmation=1" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>
                        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/yt.twinplayz" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                        <a href="https://twitter.com/TwinPlayz_YT" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                        <a href="https://github.com/ConstantineLinardakis" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

css code -

```css
/* Fourth Media Querie */

@media(max-width: 805px){
    nav .logo{
        margin: 6px;
        font-size: 25px;
        cursor: pointer;
        display:inherit;
    }

    nav .mainMenu {
        height: 100vh;
        position: fixed;
        top: -100%;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 10;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        background: white;
        transition: top 1s ease;
        display: flex;
    }

    nav .mainMenu .closeMenu {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 20px;
        right: 20px;
        color:black;
    }

    nav .openMenu {
        display: block;
    }

    nav .mainMenu li a {
        background: none;
        font-size: 2rem;
    }

    nav .mainMenu li a:hover {
        background: none;
        color: rgb(0, 110, 255);
        font-size: 2.5rem;
        transition: ease all .5s;
    }

    .icons i {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 12px;
        color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }

    footer .contact .holder .info{
        font-size:0.8rem;
    }

}
```

js code -

```js
const mainMenu = document.querySelector('.mainMenu');
const closeMenu = document.querySelector('.closeMenu');
const openMenu = document.querySelector('.openMenu');

openMenu.addEventListener('click',show);
closeMenu.addEventListener('click',close);

function show(){
    mainMenu.style.display = 'flex';
    mainMenu.style.top = '0';
}

function close(){
    mainMenu.style.top = '-100%';
}
```

Comment: If you want to do it without any JS, checkout https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8QKOaTYvYUA&t=2s

Comment: Thank you for that @ShivamJha at the moment though just trying to figure out how to position the logo and icons correctly after the burger event.